# Hair distribution based along stripes with GeoNodes

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes, hair, procedural

I am trying to recreate/mimic a fabric with GeoNodes.
The fabric looks like this.
[image: white viscose fabric, with hair distribution along the lines]

I thought of recreating it by adding a plane with a lot of geometry, then using a wave texture (white colums, black stripes) and to only distribute hair along these black stripes.
Only I have been stuck for a while, on how to actually achieve this.

I started with following tutorials for procedural hair, only that gives me hair on the whole plane instead of only on the the black stripes.
So the (wave texture) white parts, should be hairless and the black parts (stripes) should have hair.

If anyone knows how to achieve this and help me out, please let me know!!
Open to all options :))